# not-null property references a null or transient value Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, post, h2

I´m creating a spring api rest in vscode and can´t get save my entity in h2database with Insomnia

[Produto.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4yTf.png)

```
@Entity

public class Produto {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;
}
```

[ProdutoController.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFCDe.png)

```
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/produtos")

public class ProdutoController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProdutoRepository produtoRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Produto> listar(){
        return produtoRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Produto addProduto(@RequestBody Produto produto){
        return produtoRepository.save(produto);
    }
}
```

The JSON body in localhost:8080/produtos

```
{
    "nome":"Banana"
}
```

The error message:

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : br.imd.ufrn.prods.model.Produto.nome; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : br.imd.ufrn.prods.model.Produto.nome]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Produto class is missing getters

Comment: Hmmm... not sure it's the cause of the problem.